# Of Ways to Count the Limitless Primes

Tags: language-agnostic, primes

Alright, so maybe I shouldn't have shrunk this question sooo much... I have seen the post on [the most efficient way to find the first 10000 primes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622/most-efficient-code-for-the-first-10000-prime-numbers).  I'm looking for **all possible ways**.  The goal is to have a one stop shop for primality tests.  Any and all tests people know for finding prime numbers are welcome.

And so:

- **What are all the different ways of finding primes?**

Comment: Note that you can count the number of primes below n without computing all of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_.CF.80.28x.29

Answer (score 3):

Some prime tests only work with certain numbers, for instance, the [Lucas–Lehmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_test_for_Mersenne_numbers) test only works for Mersenne numbers.

Most prime tests used for big numbers can only tell you that a certain number is "probably prime" (or, if the number fails the test, it is definitely **not** prime). Usually you can continue the algorithm until you have a very high probability of a number being prime.

Have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime) and especially its "See Also" section.

The [Miller-Rabin test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_test) is, I think, one of the best tests. In its standard form it gives you probable primes - though it has been shown that if you apply the test to a number beneath 3.4*10^14, and it passes the test for each parameter 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and 17, it is *definitely* prime.

The [AKS test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) was the first deterministic, proven, general, polynomial-time test. However, to the best of my knowledge, its best implementation turns out to be slower than other tests unless the input is ridiculously large.

Answer (score 2):

[The Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a decent algorithm:

> 1. Take the list of positive integers 2 to any given Ceiling.
> 2. Take the next item in the list (2 in the first iteration) and remove all multiples of it (beyond the first) from the list.
> 3. Repeat step two until you reach the given Ceiling.
> 4. Your list is now composed purely of primes.

There is a functional limit to this algorithm in that it exchanges speed for memory.  When generating very large lists of primes the memory capacity needed skyrockets.

Comment: the crucial detail is missing here: how do you find, and how do you "remove" the multiples. If you find them in a proper way, i.e. counting up from a prime in steps of that prime, **you can't remove them at all**, because then you **can't count**. The point to SoE is *marking* the multiples, using their *values* as *addresses*, without any comparison of values (thus avoiding extra `log n` factor in complexity). This is exactly like what makes integer sorts faster than comparison sorts. You forgo that advantage if you're actually *removing* them.

Answer (score 2):

For a given integer, the fastest primality check I know is:

> 1. Take a list of 2 to the square root of **the integer**.
> 2. Loop through the list, taking the remainder of **the integer** / **current number**
>
>    > 1. If the remainder is zero for any number in the list, then the integer is not prime.
>    > 2. If the remainder was non-zero for all numbers in the list, then the integer is prime.

It uses significantly less memory than [The Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and is generally faster for individual numbers.

Answer (score 2):

@akdom's question to me:

Looping would work fine on my previous suggestion, and you don't need to do any calculations to determine if a number is even; in your loop, simply skip every even number, as shown below:

```
//Assuming theInteger is the number to be tested for primality.
// Check if theInteger is divisible by 2.  If not, run this loop.
//  This loop skips all even numbers.
for( int i = 3; i < sqrt(theInteger); i + 2) 
{
    if( theInteger % i == 0) 
    {
       //getting here denotes that theInteger is not prime 
       // somehow indicate that some number, i, divides it and break
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Rutgers grad student recently found a [recurrence relation that generates primes](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.html). The difference of its successive numbers will generate either primes or 1's.

```
a(1) = 7
a(n) = a(n-1) + gcd(n,a(n-1)).
```

It makes a lot of crap that needs to be filtered out. Benoit Cloitre also has this recurrence that does a similar task:

```
b(1) = 1
b(n) = b(n-1) + lcm(n,b(n-1))
```

then the ratio of successive numbers, minus one [b(n)/b(n-1)-1] is prime. A full account of all this can be read at [Recursivity](http://recursed.blogspot.com/2008/07/rutgers-graduate-student-finds-new.html).

For the sieve, you can do better by using a wheel instead of adding one each time, check out the [Improved Incremental Prime Number Sieves](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.835). Here is an example of a wheel. Let's look at the numbers, 2 and 5 to ignore. Their wheel is, [2,4,2,2].

Answer (score 0):

In your algorithm using the list from 2 to the root of the integer, you can improve performance by only testing odd numbers after 2.  That is, your list only needs to contain 2 and all odd numbers from 3 to the square root of the integer.  This cuts the number of times you loop in half without introducing any more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

@theprise

If I were wanting to use an incrementing loop instead of an instantiated list (problems with memory for massive numbers...), what would be a good way to do that without building the list?

It doesn't seem like it would be cheaper to do a divisibility check for the given integer (X % 3) than just the check for the normal number (N % X).

Answer (score -1):

If you're wanting to find a way of generating prime numbers, this have been covered in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622/most-efficient-code-for-the-first-10000-prime-numbers#2753).