# Working with heterogenous data in a statically typed language (F#)

Tags: c#, .net, f#

One of F#'s claims is that it allows for interactive scripting and data manipulation / exploration. I've been playing around with F# trying to get a sense for how it compares with Matlab and R for data analysis work.  Obviously F# does not have all practical functionality of these ecosystems, but I am more interested in the general advantages / disadvantages of the underlying language.

For me the biggest change, even over the functional style, is that F# is statically typed. This has some appeal, but also often feels like a straightjacket. For instance, I have not found a convenient way to deal with heterogeneous rectangular data -- think dataframe in R. Assume I'm reading a CSV file with names (string) and weights (float).  Typically I load data in, perform some transformations, add variables, etc, and then run analysis. In R, the first part might look like:

```
df <- read.csv('weights.csv')
df$logweight <- log(df$weight)
```

In F#, it's not clear what structure I should use to do this. As far as I can tell I have two options: 1) I can define a class first that is strongly typed (Expert F# 9.10) or 2) I can use a heterogeneous container such as ArrayList.  A statically typed class doesn't seem feasible because I need to add variables in an ad-hoc manner (logweight) after loading the data.  A heterogeneous container is also inconvenient because every time I access a variable I will need to unbox it.  In F#:

```
let df = readCsv("weights.csv")
df.["logweight"] = log(double df.["weight"])
```

If this were once or twice, it might be okay, but specifying a type *every* time I use a variable doesn't seem reasonable. I often deal with surveys with 100s of variables that are added/dropped, split into new subsets and merged with other dataframes.

Am I missing some obvious third choice? Is there some fun and light way to interact and manipulate heterogeneous data? If I need to do data analysis on .Net, my current sense is that I should use IronPython for all the data exploration / transformation / interaction work, and only use F#/C# for numerically intensive parts.  Is F# inherently the wrong tool for quick and dirty heterogeneous data work?

Comment: Very good, clearly stated question.  I look forward to the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that there are a few other options.

#### `(?)` operator

As Brian mentioned, you can use the `(?)` operator:

```
type dict<'a,'b> = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<'a,'b>

let (?) (d:dict<_,_>) key = unbox d.[key]
let (?<-) (d:dict<_,_>) key value = d.[key] <- box value

let df = new dict<string,obj>()
df?weight <- 50.
df?logWeight <- log(df?weight)
```

This does use boxing/unboxing on each access, and at times you may need to add type annotations:

```
(* need annotation here, since we could try to unbox at any type *)
let fltVal = (df?logWeight : float)
```

#### Top level identifiers

Another possibility is that rather than dynamically defining properties on existing objects (which F# doesn't support particularly well), you can just use top level identifiers.

```
let dfLogWeight = log(dfWeight)
```

This has the advantage that you will almost never need to specify types, though it may clutter your top-level namespace.

#### Property objects

A final option which requires a bit more typing and uglier syntax is to create strongly typed "property objects":

```
type 'a property = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<obj,'a>

let createProp() : property<'a> = new property<'a>()
let getProp o (prop:property<'a>) : 'a = prop.[o]
let setProp o (prop:property<'a>) (value:'a) = prop.[o] <- value

let df = new obj()
let (weight : property<double>) = createProp()
let (logWeight : property<double>) = createProp()

setProp df weight 50.
setProp df logWeight (getProp df weight)
let fltVal = getProp df logWeight
```

This requires each property to be explicitly created (and requires a type annotation at that point), but no type annotations would be required after that.  I find this much less readable than the other options, although perhaps defining an operator to replace `getProp` would alleviate that somewhat.

Answer (score 8):

> Is F# inherently the wrong tool for
>   quick and dirty heterogeneous data
>   work?

For completely ad hoc, exploratory data mining, I wouldn't recommend F# since the types would get in your way.

*However*, if your data is very well defined, then you can hold disparate data types in the same container by mapping all of your types to a common F# union:

```
> #r "FSharp.PowerPack";;

--> Referenced 'C:\Program Files\FSharp-1.9.6.16\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.dll'

> let rawData =
    "Name: Juliet
     Age: 23
     Sex: F
     Awesome: True"

type csv =
    | Name of string
    | Age of int
    | Sex of char
    | Awesome of bool

let parseData data =
    String.split ['\n'] data
    |> Seq.map (fun s ->
        let parts = String.split [':'] s
        match parts.[0].Trim(), parts.[1].Trim() with
        | "Name", x -> Name(x)
        | "Age", x -> Age(int x)
        | "Sex", x -> Sex(x.[0])
        | "Awesome", x -> Awesome(System.Convert.ToBoolean(x))
        | data, _ -> failwithf "Unknown %s" data)
    |> Seq.to_list;;

val rawData : string =
  "Name: Juliet
     Age: 23
     Sex: F
     Awesome: True"
type csv =
  | Name of string
  | Age of int
  | Sex of char
  | Awesome of bool
val parseData : string -> csv list

> parseData rawData;;
val it : csv list = [Name "Juliet"; Age 23; Sex 'F'; Awesome true]
```

`csv list` is strongly typed and you can pattern match over it, but you have to define all of your union constructors up front.

I personally prefer this approach, since is orders of magnitude better than working with an untyped ArrayList. However, I'm not really sure what you're requirements are, and I don't know a good way to represent ad-hoc variables (except maybe as a `Map{string, obj}`) so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if F# is a great tool here or not.  But there is a third option - the question mark operator.  I've been meaning to blog about this for a while now; [Luca's recent PDC talk](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT11) demo'd a CSV reader with C# 'dynamic', and I wanted to code a similar thing with F# using the (?) operator.  See

[F# operator "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890794/f-operator)

for a short description.  You can try to blaze ahead and play around with this on your own, or wait for me to blog about it.  I have not tried it myself in earnest so I'm not sure exactly how well it will work out.

EDIT

I should add that Luca's talk shows how 'dynamic' in C# addresses at least a portion of this question for that language.

EDIT

See also

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/12622.aspx

where I post some basic starter CSV code.