# could i get the xml tree available as intellisense in functional languages?

Tags: xml, f#, functional-programming

In F# I would like to do something like this.

```
let xml = XDocument.Load(url);
```

The xml could be dynamically parsed and I would get the xml tree available in intellisense.

```
let products = xml.root.products;
```

arrays could be filterable while values and attributes directly available

```
let productSoap = xml.root.products.Where(o => o.productName == "Soap");
let documentName = xml.root.DocumentName;
```

Why do I need to use System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq in a functional language to parse xml?

Comment: Maybe type providers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503921/f-type-providers-and-data-processing

Comment: Thx, just what I was looking for. To bad I need to wait for F# 3.0

Answer (score 1):

The comments below are correct, you will unfortunately need to wait for F#'s Type Providers features in order to do this at 'develop time'. (So that F#'s IntelliSense will do the XML parsing and provide you with data while you are writing your code.)

However, in the mean time you can use the [XSD.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to generate a .NET library wrapping an XML document. See a quick tutorial [here](http://sharpertutorials.com/using-xsd-tool-to-generate-classes-from-xml/).

The workflow is you:

1. Feed an XML document to xsd.exe
2. XSD.exe will output an assembly which can load/strongly type that XML document

IIRC, xsd.exe was written long before LINQ and more 'modern' .NET features, so the generated object model is a little clunky. However, it is better than just parsing the document yourself and using XPath to blindly query into the data.

Here's a code snippet from the tutorial:

```
      StreamReader str = new StreamReader("cd_catalog.xml");
      XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CATALOG));

      CATALOG myCdCatalogue = (CATALOG)xSerializer.Deserialize(str);

      foreach (CATALOG.CDRow cd in myCdCatalogue.CD)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(cd.TITLE);
        Console.WriteLine(cd.ARTIST);
        Console.WriteLine(cd.COUNTRY);
        Console.WriteLine(cd.COMPANY);
        Console.WriteLine(cd.PRICE);
        Console.WriteLine(cd.YEAR);
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      str.Close();
```