# In the F# API, is there something like Option.ofNull?

Tags: f#

Many APIs that I consume from F# allow null values. I like turning them into Options. Is there a simple built-in way to do this? Here is one way I have done so:

```
type Option<'A> with
    static member ofNull (t:'T when 'T : equality) =
        if t = null then None else Some t
```

Then I'm able to use `Option.ofNull` like so:

```
type XElement with
    member x.El n = x.Element (XName.Get n) |> Option.ofNull
```

Is there something built-in that already does this?

Based on Daniel's answer, `equality` isn't needed. `null` constraint can be used instead.

```
type Option<'A> with
    static member ofNull (t:'T when 'T : null) =
        if t = null then None else Some t
```

Comment: I'd call it `Option.ofObj` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077105/is-there-conditional-access-operator-in-f-similar-to-new-in-c#comment37130992_24077479

Comment: I suggested that we add a common function to the F# API for this. Vote it up here: http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6103054-add-option-ofnull-to-help-remove-nulls

Comment: Good work - I have my votes tied up at the moment myself :(

Comment: Just to point out any readers - as of F#4 this is now built into FSharp.Core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to do this. BTW, you can do without the equality constraint:

```
//'a -> 'a option when 'a : null
let ofNull = function
    | null -> None
    | x -> Some x
```

or, if you want to handle F# values passed from other languages and `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`:

```
//'a -> 'a option
let ofNull x = 
    match box x with
    | null -> None
    | _ -> Some x
```

Comment: As you say, for the purposes of this function, it's better not to have the `null` constraint on the type parameter, but I'm not sure boxing is the best way to remove the type constraint here -- why does it make sense for this function to accept value types? Another way to implement this would be to manually specify the `not struct` constraint on the type parameter, then use `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(null, x)` to check for null.

Comment: @JackP.: Those are reasonable improvements. Of course, you could avoid `box` with just a type annotation: `let ofNull (x: obj) = ...`