# F# Syntax Question

Tags: f#

A bit of a sytax question...

I have the following code in F#

```
let GetSumOfSequenceAttempt1 : bigint = 
    seq{bigint(1)..bigint(10000000)}
    |> Seq.sum
```

I dont what to keep having to place the numbers within the bigint() - is there some shorthand that will make this look neater?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

```
let GetSumOfSequenceAttempt1 = 
  seq { 1I .. 10000000I }
  |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: If I wanted to see all the abbreviations, is there some page on msdn I can go to? What would you call this?

Comment: That syntax is called the "literal" syntax.  All F# literals are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233193.aspx.

Comment: @Mark - See also [Section 6.4.1 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc264041883) which also covers the fact that the suffixes Q, R, Z, I, N, G can be used for user-defined literals (and see [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181613/hidden-features-of-f/1846741#1846741) for a particularly handy use of this technique).