# What's wrong with my logger computational expression?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

Below the computation expression I'm trying to implement. The value is wrapped in a tuple where the second item of the tuple is a list of strings representings the log entries along the way.

```
type LoggerBuilder() = 
    member this.Bind(vl : 'a * string list, f) = 
        let value = vl |> fst
        let logs = vl |> snd

        let appendLogs logs tpl =
            let value = vl |> fst
            let log = vl |> snd
            (value, logs |> List.append log)             

        (f value) |> appendLogs logs

    member this.Return(x) = 
        (x, [])
```

However, when I run the following, I didn't get the expected result. I wonder where did I missed.

```
let log = new LoggerBuilder()

let a = log {
    let! a = (1, ["assign 1"])
    let! b = (2, ["assign 2"])
    return a + b
}

// Result:
val a : int * string list = (1, ["assign 1"; "assign 1"])

// Expected:
val a : int * string list = (3, ["assign 1"; "assign 2"])
```

**Update**

To avoid this error, pass the [`--warnon:1182`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450155/whats-wrong-with-my-logger-computational-expression/22450391#comment34216267_22450391) to the command prompt of `fsi` or `fsc`. This will raise a warning for unused "variables".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the implementation of `appendLogs` function. There, you don't use the `tpl` parameter, but use the outer scope's `vl` instead, which contains only value and log for the current part of computation. You also need to flip arguments for `List.append`, otherwise the log will be backwards.

With both these fixes, your function would look like this:

```
let appendLogs logs tpl =
   let value = tpl |> fst
   let log = tpl |> snd
   (value, log |> List.append logs)
```

And with this you should get the expected result.

I also would like to add that by using destructuring in the first method parameter and later in a `let` binding, your `Bind` function could be implemented somewhat simpler:

```
member this.Bind((x, log) : 'a * string list, f) = 
    let y, nextLog = f x
    y, List.append log nextLog
```

Comment: Thanks. now I feel so ashamed to miss out `tpl`.

Comment: A very helpful trick is to use the command-line option "--warnon:1182", which warns for unused variables. That would have caught this error, I think. See [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3138320/1136133) and [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx)

Comment: @Grundoon tried it and it worked like charm. I wonder why it isn't enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your bind operator can be simply this:

```
    member this.Bind((value, log), f) = 
        let (value', log') = f value
        value', log @ log'
```

The idiomatic way to take a tuple apart is to pattern match it. I avoid the name `vl` for the tuple and instead match directly into `value` and `log` in the argument list.

Second, recall that `let!` bindings are rewritten from this:

```
let! a = (1, ["assign 1"])
...
```

to this:

```
LoggerBuilder.Bind((1, ["assign 1"]), (fun a -> ...))
```

The `f` function in your `Bind` represents whatever happens *after* the current binding. Well, what happens after is that you use the value `a` in the `...`; that is, in `Bind`, you must apply `f` to `value`. The `f` will then return the result of the entire computation, we put that in `value'`, as well as the logs accumulated, we put that in `log'`.

Comment: The last statement in the `Bind` method should be `value', log |> List.append log'`. Other than, I like your answer because it's terse. However, I marked MisterMetaphor's answer as the correct one since it answers my question.

Comment: Whoops. You're right, I updated my answer. (Note the use of the infix `@` append operator.)