# F# List SelectMany

Tags: f#, linq

This is quite simple question but I didn't find an answer:

Is there any Seq/List operation in F# to match the LINQ SelectMany?

- I know I can use System.Linq in F# if I
  want to.
- I know I can make a recursive method
  and use F# Computation Expressions
  (and make even more powerful things).

But if I try to prove that F# List operations are more powerful than LINQ...

- .Where = List.filter
- .Select = List.map
- .Aggregate = List.fold
- ...

In C# SelectMany usage syntax is pretty simple:

```
var flattenedList = from i in items1
                    from j in items2
                    select ...
```

Is there any easy direct match, List.flatten, List.bind or something like that?

SelectMany has a couple of signatures, but the most complex one seems to be:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector, 
    Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector
);
```

In F# terms this would be:

```
('a -> 'b list) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a list -> 'c list
```

Comment: How would you show that F# list is more powerful than C# list?  If it is a matter of which one has more functions for it, that doesn't show more powerful, just more bloated.  Are you trying to show that there is something you can do in F# that you can't with C#, using lists?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`collect` is the F# equivalent of SelectMany however it doesn't provide all the overloads.  Here's how to make the one you referenced.

```
let selectMany (ab:'a -> 'b seq) (abc:'a -> 'b -> 'c) input =
    input |> Seq.collect (fun a -> ab a |> Seq.map (fun b -> abc a b))
// gives
// val selectMany : ('a -> seq<'b>) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> seq<'a> -> seq<'c>
```

I believe F# doesn't provide all the SelectMany overloads because they would add noise to the library.  Here's all four overloads to [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618(v=VS.95).aspx) in Microsoft Naming.

```
let selectMany (source : 'TSource seq) (selector : 'TSource -> 'TResult seq) =
    source |> Seq.collect selector

let selectMany (source : 'TSource seq) (selector : 'TSource -> int -> 'TResult seq) =
    source |> Seq.mapi (fun n s -> selector s n) |> Seq.concat

let selectMany (source : 'TSource) 
               (collectionSelector : 'TSource -> 'TCollection seq)
               (resultSelector : 'TSource -> 'TCollection -> 'TResult) =
    source 
    |> Seq.collect (fun sourceItem -> 
        collectionSelector sourceItem 
        |> Seq.map (fun collection -> resultSelector sourceItem collection))

let selectMany (source : 'TSource) 
               (collectionSelector : 'TSource -> int -> 'TCollection seq)
               (resultSelector : 'TSource -> 'TCollection -> 'TResult) =
    source 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun n sourceItem -> 
        collectionSelector sourceItem n
        |> Seq.map (fun collection -> resultSelector sourceItem collection))
    |> Seq.concat
```

"F# List operations are more powerful than LINQ..."  While seq / list operations are great some real "F# power" comes from [Function Composition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/06/14/function-composition.aspx) and [Currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448/f-curried-function).

```
// function composition
let collect selector = Seq.map selector >> Seq.concat
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use List.collect or Seq.Collect:

```
let items1 = [1; 2; 3]
let items2 = [4; 5; 6]
let flat = items1 |> List.collect (fun i1 -> items2 |> List.map (fun i2 -> [i1, i2]))
```

That would be roughly equivalent to the following C# code:

```
var flat = from i1 in items1
           from i2 in items2
           select new { i1, i2 };
```

Answer (score 5):

Other posts show how to match the linq with

Starting with this linq:

```
var flattenedList = from i in items1
                    from j in items2
                    select ...
var flattenedList2 = items1.SelectMany(i => items2.Map(j => ...))
```

Equivalent F# is:

```
let flattenedList = seq {
    for a in items1 do
    for b in items2 do
        yield ... }
let flattenedList2 = items1 |> Seq.collect (fun i -> items2 |> Seq.map (fun j -> ...))
```

The two bits of code are roughly equivalent in expressiveness and complexity.

With that said, let's address a specific comment in your post:

> But if I try to prove that F# List
>   operations are more powerful than
>   LINQ...

Operations in the Seq/List modules are roughly equivalent to the Enumerable/Linq extensions.

However, I'd say the killer feature for lists is the ability to **pattern match** on them. Here's a silly example which doesn't convert easily to linq:

```
let rec funky = function
    | x::y::z::rest -> (z, y)::funky(z::x::rest)
    | [y;z]-> [(z, y)]
    | [z] -> [(z, z)]
    | [] -> []
// funky [1..6]
// = (int * int) list = [(3, 2); (4, 1); (5, 3); (6, 4)]
```

This would be a bit awkward to reimplement in C#, but its dead simple to write F#.

Answer (score 4):

`Seq.bind` is what you want. `SelectMany` is really just a monadic bind :).

So you'd do:

```
seq { for i in items1 do
         for j in items2 do
            yield ....  };
```

Comment: I don't see `Seq.bind` in either the F# library or the powerpack. Did you mean `Seq.collect`?

Comment: You don't see `Seq.bind` because it's not a function in the `Seq` module; its a method of the workflow builder underlying the `seq` monoid.

Comment: @pblasucci: In principle yes, but `seq { .. }` isn't a real computation expression. It is handled specially by the compiler and `seq` isn't really a computation builder (it is just a function `seq<'a> -> seq<'a>`. So, `Seq.collect` is the right answer but it is not really used in the compiled form of the sequence expression.

Comment: This looks like a bit more imperative than the declarative SelectMany

Comment: @Tomas: Thanks for the clarification. Is the special-case handling of `seq` because it occurs so frequently, thus needing special optimization?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good options to create your own `SelectMany`, but what about using `SelectMany` directly?

```
let flatten (source : 'T seq seq) :'T seq =
    System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(source, id)
```

This is a basic call to the .net `SelectMany` with the F# [`id` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545396/whats-the-purpose-of-id-function-in-the-fsharp-core).