# How do you flatten a set while keeping the parent object?

Tags: f#

In C# you would just use `SelectMany` which has an overload for holding onto the parent object. How do you do the same thing in F#? That is, I want to iterate over a set of assemblies and return all of those assemblies that have classes implementing a specific attribute.

I know I `collect` is similar to select many, but I'm not sure how to use it while maintaining the parent (assembly) information.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to _filter_ the list of assemblies. Is that right?

Comment: Essentially right, but how do I filter without having a huge nested mess? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599657/f-list-selectmany/4600047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `SelectMany` using `collect` by applying a `map` to the collection of "children" that you want to return for each element of the "parent" collection:

Assuming you have some `source` and want to get children using `getChildren` (for each element in `source`) and then you want to calculate the result using `selectResult` that takes both child and parent, you can write the following using `SelectMany`:

```
source.SelectMany
  ( (fun parent -> getChildren parent),
    (fun parent child -> selectResult parent child ) )
```

Using `collect`, the same code looks as follows (note that the `map` operation is applied inside the lambda function that we're passing to `collect` - where `parent` is still in scope):

```
source |> Seq.collect (fun parent ->
  getChildren parent 
  |> Seq.map (fun child ->
      selectResult parent child ))
```

It is also worth noting that the behavior captured by `SelectMany` can be implemented - perhaps in a more readable way - using F# sequence expressions like this:

```
seq { for parent in source do 
        for child in getChildren parent do
          yield selectResult parent child }
```

Comment: Awesome, a lot of useful information to learn from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need `filter` instead of `collect`:

```
let hasTypeWithAttribute<'t when 't :> Attribute> (a: Assembly) = a.GetTypes() |> Array.exists (fun t -> t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof<'t>, true).Length > 0)

let assemblies = inputSet |> Set.filter hasTypeWithAttribute<AttributeName>
```

Comment: Seriously, I spent all entirely too much time on this for such a simple answer. Heh, thanks a lot!