# How to aggregate over many lists in F#

Tags: list, f#, aggregate

In F# at some point I have many lists (the actual number of them differs for input data) and I want to make an aggregation over all those lists (let say addition for simplification). So what I want to achieve is the same what List.map2 or List.map3 does but for bigger number of lists.

How can I approach it? I was wondering if this is possible to do with List.scan?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599657/f-list-selectmany

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `List.reduce` and do something like this:

```
> let lists = [[1;2;3]; [1;2;3]; [1;2;3]]
val lists : int list list = (...)

> lists |> List.reduce (List.map2 (+));;
val it : int list = [3; 6; 9]
```

What does this do?

- `List.reduce` takes a list of values (here the value is `int list`) and it aggregates them into a single value using a function that says how to merge two values. So in this case, we need to give it a function `int list -> int list -> int list` and it will call it on the first and the second list, then on the result and the third list (and so on).
- The argument `List.map2 (+)` is a function of the right type - it takes two lists and performs pairwise sum of the two lists. This is really just a shortcut for writing something like:

  ```
  lists |> List.reduce (fun list1 list2 -> 
    List.map2 (fun a b -> a + b) list1 list2)
  ```