# What's the purpose of `id` function in the FSharp.Core?

Tags: .net, f#, identity

From [Operators.id<'T> Function (F#)](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#id):

> The identity function.
>
> Parameters: x Type: 'T (The input value)
>
> Return Value: The same value
>
> F# Core Library Versions, supported in: 2.0, 4.0, Portable

Why is there a function that returns its input?

Comment: Interesting to note the mathematical background as well. Having a 'do nothing' object gives important structure. As zero is an identity for numbers under addition, and one is an identity for numbers under multiplication, so `id` is an identity for the set of functions under composition. And in functional languages you'll often want to manipulate functions as objects, perform operations over them etc.

Comment: @matt_t_gregg if you post that as an answer, I'm sure you'll get quite a few upvotes.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I was pretty happy that your answer covered the practicalities of why it was needed and used - the math thing I thought was more an interesting aside.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When working with higher-order functions (i.e. functions that return other functions and/or take other functions as parameters), you always have to provide *something* as parameter, but there isn't always an actual data transformation that you'd want to apply.

For example, the function `Seq.collect` flattens a sequence of sequences, and takes a function that returns the "nested" sequence for each element of the "outer" sequence. For example, this is how you might get the list of all grandchildren of a UI control of some sort:

```
let control = ...
let allGrandChildren = control.Children |> Seq.collect (fun c -> c.Children)
```

But a lot of times, each element of the sequence will already be a sequence by itself - for example, you may have a list of lists:

```
let l = [ [1;2]; [3;4]; [5;6] ]
```

In this case, the parameter function that you pass to `Seq.collect` needs to just return the argument:

```
let flattened = [ [1;2]; [3;4]; [5;6] ] |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x)
```

This expression `fun x -> x` is a function that just returns its argument, also known as "*identity function*".

```
let flattened = [ [1;2]; [3;4]; [5;6] ] |> Seq.collect id
```

Its usage crops up so often when working with higher-order functions (such as `Seq.collect` above) that it deserves a place in the standard library.

Another compelling example is `Seq.choose` - a function that filters a sequence of `Option` values and unwraps them at the same time. For example, this is how you might parse all strings as numbers and discard those that can't be parsed:

```
let tryParse s = match System.Int32.TryParse s with | true, x -> Some x | _ -> None
let strings = [ "1"; "2"; "foo"; "42" ]
let numbers = strings |> Seq.choose tryParse  // numbers = [1;2;42]
```

But what if you're already given a list of `Option` values to start with? The identity function to the rescue!

```
let toNumbers optionNumbers =
   optionNumbers |> Seq.choose id
```

Comment: The `Seq.choose id` example is a great one, but `Seq.collect id` is just a less readable way of saying `Seq.concat`. (That said, I'm pretty sure I've written `Seq.collect id` a number of times too and it illustrates what `id` does well!)

Comment: @TomasPetricek often one's train of thought leads to `Seq.collect id`.  Mine usually fails to take the next step to `Seq.concat`, though your comment will probably increase the chance of this happening next time.  Anyway, it's nice to have the flexibility.  I sometimes wish there were an `Id()` function in C#, and I've hand-rolled it on occasion, but the difference in type inference makes it slightly less useful.

Answer (score 17):

It's useful for certain higher order functions (functions that take functions as arguments) so that you can pass `id` as the argument instead of writing out the lambda `(fun x -> x)`.

```
[[1;2]; [3]] |> List.collect id  // [1; 2; 3]
```

Comment: In this case, you could just use `List.concat` and it would be more readable :-).

Answer (score 1):

It can be extremely useful when working with options.

I have written a small idiomatic JSON-Helper, indicating all optional fields as Option, throwing errors, if a string is passed as null, if not of type 'string option'.

Now there is a function providing a boxed output value, which can be

1. 'a -> any type but no option
2. 'b -> 'x option

In order to box the value correctly, I use

```
val |> if isOption then fnOptTransform else id
```

So I'm applying the high order function **fnOptTransform**, and by calling **id** otherwise, avoid the ugliness of coding a separate lambda (I try to avoid it, where I can..). Found it useful.