# F# Curried add20 function

Tags: f#

If anyone can point me in the direction of why this works it would be greatly appreciated.

It was from my first f# lab in class.

How is add20 working when I have no parameters set to it(Problem 2C2).

```
////function that adds 10 to it

////Problem 2C1 ///
let k = 10
let add10 z k = z + k

////End Problem 2C1///    
////Problem 2C2 ///

let z = 20
let add20 = add10 z

////End Problem 2C2//
```

Comment: I think this one will be a good read for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448/f-curried-function

Comment: Thanks for the link. Definitely need to get more research in!

Answer (score 1):

If you define an `add` function that looks like this (note that your `add10` function is actually adding its two parameters, not the `k` constant defined on the previous line):

```
let add a b = a + b
```

The F# compiler will report that the function has a type `int -> int -> int`. Now, you can actually read this in two ways:

1. `int -> int -> int` is a function that takes one `int` another  `int` and produces `int`
2. `int -> (int -> int)` is a function that takes `int` and returns `int -> int`.
   That is, you call it with one number. It returns a function that takes the other number and returns the total sum.

So, when you write `add 32 10`, you are using it in the way (1). When you write `add 10`, you get back a function as described in (2).

Comment: So my add20, is in fact the second type you described. int -> (int ->int). May I ask if I am not providing any parameter to add20, how is it taking in an int? When I run it in F# interactive, it shows  val add20 : (int -> int). Thank you for the help btw.

Comment: @ezetreezy add20 is the result of a partial function application.  The reason a function like Tomas's add function is `int -> int -> int` is that it can be thought of as a function that takes a single int parameter and returns another function that takes a single int parameter.  Your `add20` is just such a function.  That is the point that Tomas is making in his point #2 above.  Another way of looking at it is that the parameter of add20 is implicit.  This isn't a particularly idiomatic way of thinking about it, however.