# Find a prime number?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

To find whether N is a prime number we only need to look for all numbers less or equal to  sqrt(N). Why is that? I am writing a C code so trying to understand a reason behind it.

Comment: @ChssPly76: I think this is a completely valid algorithms query.

Comment: Hmm... I am writing code to implement this. How is it not programming again?

Comment: I agree, this is totally programming related. Testing primality is a very common beginner exercise, and it's quite to reasonable to want to understand why the 1..sqrt(n) method works.

Comment: Actually, you only need to check the prime numbers <=  sqrt(N) :)

Comment: Personally I disagree with this closed decision... :-/ Andrej try to understang how or why something improves its algorithm. Computes are tools for many things. Math amongst many other things!

Comment: With out theory, there wouldnt be any programming. Look at Rabin Miller . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

Comment: This is programming related or at least close enough

Comment: Andrei: While trial division is an easy way of prime testing and is fast for small primes, there are much faster ways of finding primes in general. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272/of-ways-to-count-the-limitless-primes

Comment: If I eat waffles while programming, do waffles become programming related? This is a math question. If the question were "how do I check for primes in C" or something, it would be programming related, but this is just "why do I only need to check sqrt(N)?" That's language agnostic.

Comment: the answer to your question is very easy, imagine 100, 50 is a divisor but so is 5 and 2. so you dont need to look at 50, looking at 5 and 2, is the same thing as looking at 50. and so on.

Comment: @GMan: I don't see the connection? There are very few programs involving waffles; but there are many programs that involve prime numbers.

Comment: Belongs on http://mathoverflow.net.

Comment: I guess my analogy didn't go too far. The point is, what part of the question involves programming? It's number theory, not programming. You can program it, sure, but the actual question at hand has no language, or even anything computer related to it.

Comment: @GMan Most of my computer science courses had nothing to do with a particular language or even computers. But they still made me a better programmer, are definitely *programming related* and still part of the CS curriculum

Comment: First program I ever wrote was for finding primes on a Casio calculator. This question has an answer, and is as language-specific as all the algorithm ones that float around here.

Comment: I don't understand how this: "To find whether N is a prime number we only need to look for all numbers less or equal to sqrt(N). Why is that?" is computer related at all. If you can explain that to me, please share. Note, saying 'I wrote a prime tester' doesn't make this nubmer theory question programming related.

Comment: Things are already too scattered with SO, SU and SF - plus Meta.  Sending people to more places just compounds the problems.  It doesn't belong on SU or SF or Meta; it is loosely related to programming (you write √N if it is a maths question!), so it belongs on SO.

Comment: Even if I agree with you, it still doesn't make it programming related :)

Comment: Like I said, it's an algorithms question (it's also a number theory question, but the algorithms answer and the number theory answer may not be the same). Maybe having a look through the chapter of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming would convince you that this stuff is relevant to programming.

Comment: a discussion whether this sort of questions belongs here is here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26339/are-algorithm-questions-allowed-on-so . Hence let's limit this question to programming answers, not meta answers

Comment: GMan: By your logic, almost every question in `algorithms`, `cryptography`, `compression` and a boatload of other tags would be offtopic.  At the end of the day, programming is a applied mathematical discipline - I would agree with you if the question was *"how do I **prove** that I only need to test numbers <= sqrt(N)"*.

Comment: Algorithms are meant to be implemented on a computer, though. All deal with math, but are related computer inherently. This is pure math.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill http://mathoverflow.net/ contains more hardcore math. I doubt this simple CS-related stuff would be appropriate there.

Comment: @caf: *Proving* that an algorithm always gives the desired solution is highly programming related. In fact it's a debugging technique (labour intensive but very, *very* effective).

Comment: Agreed, but this isn't an algorithm, it's a math problem. This would be perfectly suited on mathoverflow. The question has an implicit "proof" like caf said anyway. He's asking why, that's the same as asking for a proof. Proof just sounds different, it's the same.

Comment: And just to prove my point, observe the highest voted answer. Where in that answer is there anything related to programming or computers? Nowhere. Same with all the other answers.

Comment: This is a condition required for correctness of an algorithm. There are lots of those, you'd be trying to throw out a good part of computer science. Programming != mindless hacking.

Comment: Read the thread on meta. Joel says this isn't an algorithms question. Sorry. That's not a correctness of algorithm, it's a correctness in number theory. There's a difference.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

N is prime if it is a positive integer which is divisible by exactly two positive integers, 1 and N. Since a number's divisors cannot be larger than that number, this gives rise to a simple primality test:

- If an integer N, greater than 1, is not divisible by any integer in the range `[2, N-1]`, then N is prime. Otherwise, N is not prime.

However, it would be nice to modify this test to make it faster. So let us investigate.

Note that the divisors of N occur in pairs. If N is divisible by a number M, then it is also divisible by N/M. For instance, 12 is divisble by 6, and so also by 2. Furthermore, if `M >= sqrt(N)`, then `N/M <= sqrt(N)`.

This means that if no numbers less than or equal to sqrt(N) divide N, no numbers greater than sqrt(N) divide N either (excepting 1 and N themselves), otherwise a contradiction would arise.

So we have a better test:

- If an integer N, greater than 1, is not divisible by any integer in the range `[2, sqrt(N)]`, then N is prime. Otherwise, N is not prime.

if you consider the reasoning above, you should see that a number which passes this test also passes the first test, and a number which fails this test also fails the first test. The tests are therefore equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

A composite number (one that is not prime, or 1) has at least 1 pair of factors, and it is guaranteed that one of the numbers from each pair is less than or equal to the square root of the number (which is what you are asking about).

If you square the square root of the number, you get the number itself (`sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = n`), so if you made one of the numbers bigger (than `sqrt(n)`) you would have to make the other one smaller. If you then only check the numbers 2 through `sqrt(n)` you will have checked all of the possible factors, since each of those factors will be paired with a number that is greater than `sqrt(n)` (except of course if the number is in fact a square of some other number, like 4, 9, 16, etc...but that doesn't matter since you know they aren't prime; they are easily factored by `sqrt(n)` itself).

Answer (score 5):

The reason is simple,  any number bigger than the sqrt, will cause the other multiplier, to be smaller than the sqrt. In such case, you should have already check it.

Answer (score 3):

Let *n*=*a*×*b* be composite.

Assume *a*>sqrt(*n*) and *b*>sqrt(*n*).

*a*×*b* > sqrt(*n*)×sqrt(*n*)

*a*×*b* > *n*

But we know *a*×*b*=*n*, therefore *a*<sqrt(*n*) or *b*<sqrt(*n*).

Since you only need to know *a* or *b* to show *n* is composite, you only need to check the numbers up to sqrt(*n*) to find such a number.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the worst case, number `n` can be expresed as a<sup>2</sup>.

If the number can be expressed diferently, that men that one of divisors will be less than `a = sqrt(n)`, but the other can be greater.