# Further speeding up of Sieve method of Eratosthenes to find primes

Tags: c, math, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I saw [this c code](http://c-faq.com/misc/bitsets.html) of using Sieve method of Eratosthenes to find primes, but I cannot extend it to even larger integers (for example, to 1000000000 and even larger) because of memory consumption to allocate such a large char array.

What would be the strategies to extend the code to larger numbers? Any references are also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: How is memory consumption a problem? 10**9 bits is about 120 MB, which isn't too much on today's personal computers. Actually, it seems that even 2**32 (the whole range of unsigned 32 bit integers) fits into 512 MB. Sure, that's a lot for a single application, but memory is plenty these days.

Comment: I've checked the results with two other calculators and mental arithmetic suggests the results can't be completely off. 10**9 bit is 125 * 10**6 byte (divide by 8) is roughly 122 * 10**3 kilobyte (divide by 1024) is roughly 119 megabyte (divide by 1024). Please explain how you arrive at 1GB?

Comment: @Qiang Li: Try making the array `static`.

Comment: @caf: I assume you meant to make the array global? what is the difference here, static vs. nonstatic? I am not aware of this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to make it global, you can just add the `static` storage class specifier.  Objects with static storage duration exist just once for the entire invocation of the program, so they are typically not stored on the stack but in a separate memory region.  This will make a difference to your case because the stack is normally quite limited in maximum size.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Sieve of Atkin is faster only for large (>=1e9) numbers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622/most-efficient-code-for-the-first-10000-prime-numbers/175956#175956

Comment: Sieve of Atkin implementation for small ~32bit numbers: http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html

Answer (score 2):

The standard improvement to apply would be to treat each `i`-th bit as representing the number `2*i+1`, thus representing ***odds only***, cutting the size of the array in half. This would also entail, for each new prime `p`, starting the marking-off from `p*p` and incrementing by `2*p`, to skip over evens. `2` itself is a special case. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622/most-efficient-code-for-the-first-10000-prime-numbers) with a lot of answers.

Another strategy is to switch to the ***segmented sieve***. That way you only need about `pi(sqrt(m)) = 2*sqrt(m)/log(m)` memory (`m` being your upper limit) set aside for the initial sequence of primes with which you'd sieve smaller fixed-sized array, sequentially representing segments of numbers. If you only need primes in some narrow far away range `[m-d,m]`, you'd skip directly to sieving that range after all the needed primes have been gathered, as shown e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891).

Per your specifics, to get primes up to 10^9 in value, working with one contiguous array is still possible. Using a **bitarray** for *odds only*, you'd need 10^9/16 bytes, i.e. about 60 MB of memory. Easier to work by segments; we only need 3402 primes, below 31627, to sieve each segment array below 10^9.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly because of the size of the array required, the Sieve of Eratosthenes becomes impractical at some point. A modified sieve is common to find larger primes, (as [explained on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Large_primes)).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`gmp`](http://gmplib.org/) library. See [Speed up bitstring/bit operations in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897297/4279) for the fast implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes. It should be relatively easy to translate the provided solutions to C.