# Fastest way to find all primes under 4 billion

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to print every prime number under 2**32.  Right now I'm using a bool vector to build a sieve and then print out the primes after making the sieve.  It takes 4 minutes just to print out the primes upto 1 billion.  Is there a faster way to do this?? Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  long long limit = atoll(argv[1]);
  //cin >> limit;
  long long sqrtlimit = sqrt(limit);

  vector<bool> sieve(limit+1, false);

  for(long long n = 4; n <= limit; n += 2)
    sieve[n] = true;

  for(long long n=3; n <= sqrtlimit; n = n+2){
    if(!sieve[n]){
      for(long long m = n*n; m<=limit; m=m+(2*n))
        sieve[m] = true;
    }
  }

  long long last;
  for(long long i=limit; i >= 0; i--){
    if(sieve[i] == false){
      last = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  cout << last << endl;

  for(long long i=2;i<=limit;i++)
  {
    if(!sieve[i])
      if(i != last)
        cout<<i<<",";
      else
        cout<<i;
  }
  cout<<endl;
```

Comment: It should take waaaaay more than 4 minutes to *print out* the first billion primes.

Comment: I think the fastest way would be to skip all numbers that you know arent prime, for example, numbers ending with `2`,`4`,`5` (After 5), `6`, `8`, `0`

Comment: I agree with @Mysticial it should take way longer than 4 minutes (unless you have a super computer).

Comment: no what i meant was all of the primes under 1 billion sorry edited

Comment: if it takes 4 min. for 1 billion, it should take 16 min. for 4 billion, and that's not too bad compared to waiting for an answer on SO. and once you have computed them you never need to compute them again. heck just get them off the web and be done with it!

Comment: right but i need to get the output in less than 10 seconds.  its for a competition

Comment: In order to reduce storage requirements, the information about prime or not prime was stored for 30 integers in each byte. Only one bit is needed to store prime or not prime for an integer. The value of the integer is known by the location of the bit.

In each 30 integers, for N >= 1, the numbers that might be prime are 
N*30+1, 
N*30+7, 
N*30+11, 
N*30+13, 
N*30+17, 
N*30+19, 
N*30+23, 
N*30+29 

http://www.rsok.com/~jrm/printprimes.html

Comment: Is it a competition for who can do best google search? ;-)

Comment: also, separate out your timings for generation vs printing out. there's nothing you can do about printing out and neither can your competitiors. just focus on the generation time.

Comment: competition is the wrong word.  its a challenge online.  not really competing with anyone.

Comment: If you need this answer in 10 seconds, then you're going about things the wrong way.  You can't calculate that many numbers that fast.  What do you really need to find?

Comment: 10s for *computing* the primes is not that far off.  Using wheel factorization it is possible to compute the primes up to one billion in 20s, on a single 1.83GHz core in Java.

Comment: usually the way to go is a segmented sieve with wheel factorization. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891) presents an offset sieve on odds; something to start from.

Answer (score 5):

I discuss the problem of generating large numbers of primes at my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/09/11/the-sum-of-the-first-billion-primes/), where I find the sum of the first billion primes is 11138479445180240497. I describe four different methods:

1. Brute force, testing each number starting from 2 using trial division.
2. Generate candidates using a 2,3,5,7-wheel, then test primality with strong pseudoprime tests to bases 2, 7, and 61; this method works only up to 2^32, which was insufficient for me to sum the first billion primes but will be sufficient for you.
3. An algorithm due to Melissa O'Neill that uses sieve embedded in a priority queue, which is quite slow.
4. A segmented sieve of Eratosthenes, which is very fast but requires space to store both the sieving primes and the sieve itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the sieve of erastosthenes in C++20 using with the punching of the non-prime multiples done multithreaded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <charconv>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <bit>
#include <fstream>
#include <string_view>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <new>
#include <span>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #include <intrin.h>
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    #include <cpuid.h>
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #pragma warning(disable: 26495) // uninitialized member
#endif

using namespace std;

#if defined(__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size)
constexpr ptrdiff_t CL_SIZE = hardware_destructive_interference_size;
#else
constexpr ptrdiff_t CL_SIZE = 64;
#endif

size_t getL2Size();
bool smt();

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    try
    {
        if( argc < 2 )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        auto parse = []( char const *str, auto &value )
        {
            bool hex = str[0] == '0' && tolower( str[1] ) == 'x';
            str += 2 * hex;
            auto [ptr, ec] = from_chars( str, str + strlen( str ), value, !hex ? 10 : 16 );
            return ec == errc() && !*ptr;
        };
        size_t end;
        if( !parse( argv[1], end ) )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        if( end < 2 )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        if( (ptrdiff_t)end++ < 0 )
            throw bad_alloc();
        unsigned
            hc = jthread::hardware_concurrency(),
            nThreads;
        if( argc < 4 || !parse( argv[3], nThreads ) )
            nThreads = hc;
        if( !nThreads )
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        using word_t = size_t;
        constexpr size_t
            BITS_PER_CL = CL_SIZE * 8,
            BITS = sizeof(word_t) * 8;
        size_t nBits = end / 2;
        union alignas(CL_SIZE) ndi_words_cl { word_t words[CL_SIZE / sizeof(word_t)]; ndi_words_cl() {} };
        vector<ndi_words_cl> sieveCachelines( (nBits + BITS_PER_CL - 1) / BITS_PER_CL );
        span<word_t> sieve( &sieveCachelines[0].words[0], (nBits + BITS - 1) / BITS );
        assert(to_address( sieve.end() ) <= &to_address( sieveCachelines.end() )->words[0]);
        fill( sieve.begin(), sieve.end(), -1 );
        auto punch = [&]( size_t start, size_t end, size_t prime, auto )
        {
            size_t
                bit = start / 2,
                bitEnd = end / 2;
            if( bit >= bitEnd )
                return;
            if( prime >= BITS ) [[likely]]
                do [[likely]]
                    sieve[bit / BITS] &= rotl( (word_t)-2, bit % BITS );
                while( (bit += prime) < bitEnd );
            else
            {
                auto pSieve = sieve.begin() + bit / BITS;
                do [[likely]]
                {
                    word_t
                        word = *pSieve,
                        mask = rotl( (word_t)-2, bit % BITS ),
                        oldMask;
                    do
                        word &= mask,
                        oldMask = mask,
                        mask = rotl( mask, prime % BITS ),
                        bit += prime;
                    while( mask < oldMask );
                    *pSieve++ = word;
                } while( bit < bitEnd );
            }
        };
        size_t sqrt = (ptrdiff_t)ceil( ::sqrt( (ptrdiff_t)end ) );
        for( size_t bSqrt = sqrt / 2, bit = 1; bit < bSqrt; ++bit ) [[likely]]
        {
            auto pSieve = sieve.begin() + bit / BITS;
            do [[likely]]
            {
                if( word_t w = *pSieve >> bit % BITS; w ) [[likely]]
                {
                    bit += countr_zero( w );
                    break;
                }
                ++pSieve;
                bit = bit + BITS & -(ptrdiff_t)BITS;
            } while( bit < bSqrt );
            if( bit >= bSqrt ) [[unlikely]]
                break;
            size_t prime = 2 * bit + 1;
            punch( prime * prime, sqrt, prime, false_type() );
        }
        auto scan = [&]( size_t start, size_t end, auto fn )
        {
            size_t
                bit = start / 2,
                bitEnd = end / 2;
            if( bit >= bitEnd )
                return;
            auto pSieve = sieve.begin() + bit / BITS;
            word_t word = *pSieve++ >> bit % BITS;
            for( ; ; )
            {
                size_t nextWordBit = bit + BITS & -(ptrdiff_t)BITS;
                for( unsigned gap; word; word >>= gap, word >>= 1 )
                {
                    gap = countr_zero( word );
                    bit += gap;
                    if( bit >= bitEnd ) [[unlikely]]
                        return;
                    fn( bit++ * 2 + 1, true_type() );
                }
                bit = nextWordBit;
                if( bit >= bitEnd ) [[unlikely]]
                    return;
                word = *pSieve++;
            }
        };
        static auto dbl = []( ptrdiff_t x ) { return (double)x; };
        using range_t = pair<size_t, size_t>;
        vector<range_t> ranges;
        ranges.reserve( nThreads );
        vector<jthread> threads;
        threads.reserve( nThreads );
        auto initiate = [&]( size_t start, auto fn )
        {
            ranges.resize( 0 );
            double threadRange = dbl( end - start ) / nThreads;
            for( size_t t = nThreads, trEnd = end, trStart; t--; trEnd = trStart ) [[likely]]
            {
                trStart = start + (ptrdiff_t)((ptrdiff_t)t * threadRange + 0.5);
                size_t trClStart = trStart & -(2 * CL_SIZE * 8);
                trStart = trClStart >= start ? trClStart : start;
                if( trStart < trEnd )
                    ranges.emplace_back( trStart, trEnd );
            }
            for( range_t const &range : ranges )
                if( &range != &ranges.back() )
                    threads.emplace_back( fn, range.first, range.second, true_type() );
                else
                    fn( range.first, range.second, false_type() );
            threads.resize( 0 );
        };
        double maxCacheRange = dbl( getL2Size() * 8 * 2 ) / 3 * (smt() && nThreads > hc / 2 ? 1 : 2);
        initiate( sqrt,
            [&]( size_t rStart, size_t rEnd, auto )
            {
                double thisThreadRange = dbl( rEnd - rStart );
                ptrdiff_t nCachePartitions = (ptrdiff_t)ceil( thisThreadRange / maxCacheRange );
                double cacheRange = thisThreadRange / dbl( nCachePartitions );
                for( size_t p = nCachePartitions, cacheEnd = rEnd, cacheStart; p--; cacheEnd = cacheStart ) [[likely]]
                {
                    cacheStart = rStart + (ptrdiff_t)((double)(ptrdiff_t)p * cacheRange + 0.5);
                    cacheStart &= -(2 * CL_SIZE * 8);
                    cacheStart = cacheStart >= sqrt ? cacheStart : sqrt;
                    scan( 3, sqrt,
                        [&]( size_t prime, auto )
                        {
                            size_t start = (cacheStart + prime - 1) / prime * prime;
                            start = start % 2 ? start : start + prime;
                            punch( start, cacheEnd, prime, true_type() );
                        } );
                }
            } );
        if( bool count = false; argc >= 3 && (!*argv[2] || (count = strcmp( argv[2], "*" ) == 0)) )
        {
            if( !count )
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            atomic<size_t> aNPrimes( 1 );
            initiate( 3,
                [&]( size_t rStart, size_t rEnd, auto )
                {
                    size_t nPrimes = 0;
                    scan( rStart, rEnd, [&]( ... ) { ++nPrimes; } );
                    aNPrimes.fetch_add( nPrimes, memory_order::relaxed );
                } );
            cout << aNPrimes.load( memory_order::relaxed ) << " primes" << endl;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        ofstream ofs;
        ofs.exceptions( ofstream::failbit | ofstream::badbit );
        ofs.open( argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : "primes.txt", ofstream::binary | ofstream::trunc );
        constexpr size_t
            BUF_SIZE = 0x100000,
            AHEAD = 32;
        union ndi_char { char c; ndi_char() {} };
        vector<ndi_char> rawPrintBuf( BUF_SIZE + AHEAD - 1 );
        span printBuf( &to_address( rawPrintBuf.begin() )->c, &to_address( rawPrintBuf.end() )->c );
        auto
            bufBegin = printBuf.begin(),
            bufEnd = bufBegin,
            bufFlush = bufBegin + BUF_SIZE;
        auto print = [&]() { ofs << string_view( bufBegin, bufEnd ); };
        auto printPrime = [&]( size_t prime, auto )
        {
            auto [ptr, ec] = to_chars( &*bufEnd, &bufEnd[AHEAD - 1], prime );
            if( (bool)ec ) [[unlikely]]
                throw system_error( (int)ec, generic_category(), "converson failed" );
            bufEnd = ptr - &*bufBegin + bufBegin; // pointer to iterator - NOP
            *bufEnd++ = '\n';
            if( bufEnd >= bufFlush ) [[unlikely]]
                print(), bufEnd = bufBegin;
        };
        printPrime( 2, false_type() );
        scan( 3, end, printPrime );
        print();
    }
    catch( exception const &exc )
    {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}

array<unsigned, 4> cpuId( unsigned code )
{
    array<unsigned, 4> regs;
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    __cpuid( (int (&)[4])regs, code );
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    __cpuid(code, regs[0], regs[1], regs[2], regs[3]);
#endif
    return regs;
}

bool smt()
{
    if( cpuId( 0 )[0] < 1 )
        return false;
    return cpuId( 1 )[3] >> 28 & 1;
}

size_t getL2Size()
{
    if( cpuId( 0x80000000u )[0] < 0x80000006u )
        return 512ull * 1024;
    return (cpuId( 0x80000006u )[2] >> 16) * 1024;
}
```

Almost all of the CPU time is spent in the multi-threaded code punching the non-prime multiples. Within the punching threads the bit range is partitioned to fit into the L2-cache. If the number of threads is beyond the half number of logical cores on a SMT-system the thread sub-partitions are half the size.
Ive just added storing only the odd primes, i.e no multiples of 2, thereby having about +87% more performance.
On my Ryzen 9 7950X Zen4 16-core CPU producing all primes up to 2 ^ 32, that's almost 210E6 primes, takes about 0.15 seconds on all cores with suppressed file output; on one core the algorithm takes about 1.73 seconds. The program's third parameter is the number of threads. With 16 threads on my 16 core Zen4-machine the code I get a scaling of 70% over one thread. Occupying further SMT siblings brings almost no further speedup as the code depends on the throughput of the L2-cache.
The file output is done with to_chars and my own buffering to speed up the I/O. Producing a 2.2GB file from the mentioned range takes about an additional two seconds on my computer (64GB, PCIe 4.0 SSD).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably speed it up a bit:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> numbers;
    unsigned long long maximum = 4294967296;
    for (unsigned long long i = 2; i <= maximum; ++i)
    {
        if (numbers.empty())
        {
            numbers.push_back(i);
            continue;
        }

        if (std::none_of(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [&](unsigned long long p)
        {
            return i % p == 0;
        }))
        {
            numbers.push_back(i);
        }

    }

    std::cout << "Primes:  " << std::endl;
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

It is kind of the inverse of the Sieve of Eratosthenes (instead of starting with every number under the limit and eliminating multiples, it starts at 2 and ignores multiples up to the limit).

Comment: Yes.  It compiles and runs (but times out) on ideone.  Compiling and running it with VS2010 and VS2012 takes about 2 minutes on my computer.

Comment: Take that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928095/fastest-way-to-find-all-primes-under-4-billion/77607710#77607710 - I've got only one idea to improve that by storing only odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would probably be to take a pregenerated list.

http://www.bigprimes.net/ has the first 1.4 billion primes available for download, which should include every prime under 30 billion or so.

I suppose loading the binary might take too long when it is a few gigabytes in size.

Comment: online contest sites usually accept only source code, and have source code size limit that would prevent this.

Comment: It is generally accepted among programmers who deal regularly with prime numbers that it is faster to generate primes than to read them from a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you benchmarked what is taking the most time? Is it the sieve itself, or the writing of the output?

One quick way to speed up the sieve is to stop worrying about all the even numbers. There's only one even number that's a prime and you can hard-code it. That cuts the size of your array in half which will help immensely if you're bumping up against the limits of physical memory.

```
vector<bool> sieve((limit+1)/2, false);
...
  for(long long m = n*n/2; m<=limit/2; m=m+n)
    sieve[m] = true;
```

As for the output itself, `cout` is notoriously inefficient. It might be more efficient to call `itoa` or some equivalent yourself, then use `cout.write` to output it. You might even go old school and use `fwrite` with `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a fast way in C to output primes up to 4 billion in under three minutes using a single thread on my Ryzen 9 3900x.
If you output it to a file, it ends up being 2.298GB and I think it uses about 20GB of memory to complete.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRSIZE 4000000000
#define MAXCALC ARRSIZE/2

int main() {
    long int z;
    long int *arr = (long int*) malloc((ARRSIZE) * sizeof(long int));
    for (long int x=3;x <= MAXCALC; x++) {
        if (x % 10 == 3 || x % 10 == 7 || x % 10 == 9) {
            for (long int y=3; y < MAXCALC; y++){
                    z = x * y;
                    if (z < ARRSIZE)
                        arr[z] = 1;
                    else
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("2 3 5 ");
    for (long int x=7; x < ARRSIZE; x++) {
        if (x % 2 != 0 && x % 10 != 5)
            if (arr[x] != 1)
                printf("%ld ", x);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(arr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code i python that outputs all primes less than a billion in 8.7 seconds. But I was unsure if you ment the first 4 billion primes or allan primes less than that. Anyways, here is my solution:

```py
import numpy as np
from math import isqrt

def all_primes_less_than(n):
    is_prime = np.full(n,True)
    is_prime[:2] = False
    is_prime[4::2] = False
    for p in range(3,isqrt(n),2):
        if is_prime[p]: is_prime[p*p::p] = False
    return is_prime.nonzero()[0]
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33347321)

Comment: @Viktor Jonsson: The above C++20 code from me is about 117 times faster than the Python code.