# c++ sieve of Eratosthenes my code is slow

Tags: c++, time-complexity, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to find the number of prime numbers below 400 million but even with just 40 million my code is taking 8 secs to run. what am i doing wrong?

what can i do to make it faster?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<bool> k;                         
    vector<long long int> c;                
    for (int i=2;i<40000000;i++)
    {
        k.push_back(true);                  
        c.push_back(i);
    }

    for ( int i=0;i<sqrt(40000000)+1;i++)                            
    {                                                               
        if (k[i]==true)                                              
       {                                                            
           for (int j=i+c[i];j<40000000;j=j+c[i])                  
           {                                                       
               k[j]=false; 
           }
       }
    }
    vector <long long int> arr;
    for ( int i=0;i<40000000-2;i++)
    {
        if (k[i]==true)
        {
            arr.push_back(c[i]);
        }
    }
    cout << arr.size() << endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your task is a slow one.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD  do you mind suggesting me some improvements.

Comment: [*Empirical Orders of Growth, **please!***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) To make it faster switch to segmented sieve, this is supposed to improve the cache locality. You don't need the vector `c` at all, just maintain a counter. Always start from `i=2`. Switch to working on odds only, `for i=3; ...; i+= 2`. Use odds-packed arrays where `p=2i+start_value` [or something](http://ideone.com/fapob).

Comment: you can also initialize the `k` array all at once with `s.resize(40000000, true)`, you know its size. -- and, `sqrt(40000000) = 6324.555`, always. simply declaring a new var to hold this value outside the for loop will make certain that it is optimized. -- do look into the Ideone entry I linked above - it runs ~0.23 sec for 40M and ~3.6 sec for 400M ([***which means it is growing at ~n^1.2 empirically***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)), and it isn't even segmented. Ideone is slow, your machine should be about 3 times faster than that or so.

Comment: @WillNess rather than just reserve memory all at once, you can also just fill the vector up-front without a need to push_back at all. see my answer for details

Comment: @WillNess sorry I misread your comment as `reserve` not `resize`. my bad

Comment: When marking off the multiples of a prime `p`, you can start from `p*p`; all of the smaller multiples of `p` have already been marked off.

Comment: Why `long long int` rather than, say, `int32_t`?  Similarly, `i` and `j` should probably be of type `int32_t` or `int32_fast_t`; technically, you're not guaranteed that `int` is capable of holding numbers this large (although it's common that it can).

Comment: Take that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928095/fastest-way-to-find-all-primes-under-4-billion/77607710#77607710 - I've got only one idea to improve that by storing only odd numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I profiled your code as well as a simple tweak, below. The tweak is more than twice as fast:

```
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //original version
    vector<bool> k;                         
    vector<long long int> c;                
    for (int i=2;i<40000000;i++)
      {
        k.push_back(true);                  
        c.push_back(i);
      }

    for ( int i=0;i<sqrt(40000000)+1;i++)                            
      {                                                               
        if (k[i]==true)                                              
          {                                                            
            for (int j=i+c[i];j<40000000;j=j+c[i])                  
              {                                                       
                k[j]=false; 
              }
          }
      }
    vector <long long int> arr;
    for ( int i=0;i<40000000-2;i++)
      {
        if (k[i]==true)
          {
            arr.push_back(c[i]);
          }
      }
    cout << arr.size() << endl ;


    auto end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Elapsed = " << 
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end1 - start).count() <<
      std::endl;

  }

  {

    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //new version

    const long limit{40000000};
    vector<bool> k(limit-1,true);  

    //k[0] is the number 0
    k[0]=false; k[1]=false;

    auto sq = sqrt(limit) + 1;

    //start at the number 2
    for ( int i=2;i<sq;i++)                            
      {                                                               
        if (k[i]==true)                                              
          {                                                            
            for (int j=i+i;j<limit;j+=i)                  
              {                                                       
                k[j]=false; 
              }
          }
      }


    vector <long long int> arr;
    for ( int i=0;i<limit-2;i++)
      {
        if (k[i]==true)
          {
            arr.push_back(i);
          }
      }
    cout << arr.size() << endl ;



    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Elapsed = " << 
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - begin).count() <<
      std::endl;

  }
```

Here is the output (elapsed in milliseconds), in Debug mode:

```
2433654
Elapsed = 5787
2433654
Elapsed = 2432
```

Both have same results, second is much faster.

Here is another version using some nice C++ features (requiring less code), and it is about 11% faster than the second version above:

```
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const long limit{40000000};
    vector<int> k(limit-1,0);

    //fill with sequence of integers
    std::iota(k.begin(),k.end(),0);

    //k[0] is the number 0
    //integers reset to 0 are not prime
    k[0]=0; k[1]=0;

    auto sq = sqrt(limit) + 1;

    //start at the number 2
    for (int i=2;i<sq;i++)                            
      {                                                               
        if (k[i])
          {                                                            
            for (int j=i+i;j<limit;j+=i)                  
              {                                                       
                k[j]=0; 
              }
          }
      }

    auto results = std::remove(k.begin(),k.end(),0);

    cout << results - k.begin() << endl ;


    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Elapsed = " << 
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - begin).count() <<
      std::endl;

  }
```

Note that in your original version, you `push_back` in three different places, while this use of modern idioms never uses `push_back` at all when operating on the `vector`s.

In this example, the `vector` is of `int`s so that you have the actual list of prime numbers when you are finished.

Output:

```
2433654
Elapsed = 2160
```

These above are all Debug mode numbers.

In Release mode, the best is a combination of the second and third techniques above, using the numeric with a vector of bools, if you don't care what the actual prime numbers are in the end:

```
2433654
Elapsed = 1098
2433654
Elapsed bool remove= 410
2433654
Elapsed = 779
```

Note that your original code only takes about 1 second on my 5 year-old laptop in Release mode, so you are probably running in Debug mode.

Comment: did you check the [empirical orders of growth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness?tab=profile) for your last variant (with the iterators and iota)? I can't imagine it being better than the vector<bool> code, with that much more memory use.

Comment: @WillNess the best variant I posted in my last section used vector of bool as I noted. But the vector of int is provided in the event the user wants a condensed list of the actual prime numbers themselves (rather than the count only)

Comment: @johnbakers thank you for the answer can you tell me how to change to realease mode

Answer (score 4):

I got it down from taking 10 seconds to run to just half a second on my computer by changing two things. First, I'm guessing you didn't compile it with optimization enabled. That brought it from 10 seconds down to 1 second for me. Second, the vector c is unnecessary. Everywhere you have `c[i]` in your code you can replace it with `i+2`. This will make it run twice as fast.

Comment: I'm using code blocks 13.12 on a intel i5-5200,8GB DDR3 machine. I've checked the optimize fully option in compiler settings but still it takes the same amount.  what are the other ways to optimize the speed

Comment: Remove the c vector. That will make it twice as fast.

Comment: @Nikhil also make sure you are not in Debug mode. That caused mine to take 5x longer than Release mode (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove vector c, you don't need it.
2. Create vector k with known size at start. Repeatedly appending elements to a vector by invoking `push_back()` is a really bad idea from a performance point of view, as it can cause repeated memory reallocations and copies.
3. http://primesieve.org/segmented_sieve.html - segmented version for inspiration.
4. You can skip processing multiples of 2 and 3. [link from code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7342/89484)
5. It looks that you've got some issue in compiler optimization flag settings. Maybe you didn't change configuration from debug to release. What is your release speedup vs debug one?