# Find the prime numbers in specific interval

Tags: c++, primes

I have to find prime numbers for t cases. Examples of input / output below:

```
Input:
2
1 10
3 5

Output:
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

Notice the space between the answers as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool prime (int x, int y);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, x, y;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        cin >> x >> y;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
            cout << prime(x, y) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool prime(int x, int y){
    bool prime = true;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++){
        for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
            if (i % j == 0)
                prime = false;
    return prime;
    }
}
```

My program outputs only 1 all the time, why is that?

Comment: t means the amount of test cases <= 10. For example, in the example it's 2, means I have to output the prime numbers in 2 intervals.

Comment: You have a function that returns `true` if any number in the range is prime, and you keep calling that and printing the result. Perhaps you should find the set of prime numbers and print each of those.

Comment: I don't know how much it will affect your program, but I would recommend changing your inner loop in `main()` to use a variable name other than `i`. It's just good practice to not overshadow variables like that.

Comment: better to use the [offset sieve of Eratothenes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19641049/849891). C code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891). You will have to know the range of your tests in advance, or you'll have to extend the core array as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are outputting the result of `prime(x, y)`, which is a `bool`.  This will always be zero or one.