# Finding prime numbers in specific interval

Tags: c++, primes

Find prime numbers in specific interval in specific amount of test cases.

Example is below:
Input:

```
2
1 10
3 5
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

Notice the little space between the answer also.

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void prime (int x, int y);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, x[10], y[10];
    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        //for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];

    while (t > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
            prime(x[i], y[i]);
        t--;
    }
}

void prime(int x, int y){
    bool prime = true;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++){
        for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++){
            prime = true;
            if (i % j == 0)
                prime = false;
        }
        if (prime == true)
            cout << i << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here's the output I get when I use the same input.

```
1
2
3
5
7
10

3
5

1
2
3
5
7
10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use [offset sieve of Eratothenes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19641049/849891). C code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since no one's pointed it out yet, if you're wondering why you're getting three sets of output instead of two...

```
while (t > 0){
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    prime(x[i], y[i]);
  t--;
}
```

might be better phrased as

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
  prime(x[i], y[i]);
```

(The outer loop is what gives you extra output.)

Answer (score 1):

You should move `prime = true` outside of the for loop. You are currently resetting it at every iteration. As far as the printing, you don't need that `<< endl` when you print each line. You only need a space.

Comment: I moved it in the first for() loop and it seems to fix the problem with the primes, but it still executes 3 times for some reason, the first interval is calculated twice, any reason for that?