# How can I optimize my sieve of Eratosthenes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10, replit, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I made a sieve of Eratosthenes in python, and it can sort 10,000 numbers in 2 seconds. But I want to optimize this script further. Additionally, I would like to have a readout on what number it is sorting (e.g. "Removing multiples of 2 (4982)...") but this slows down performance too much to be a practical idea.

I tried optimizing by removing the temporary variable, but it took longer to get the index of the number in the primes list and use it instead. I also tried eliminating all uses of the sys and colorama module, but the impact on performance was negligible.
Test data:
10,000 numbers without readout: 2.1s
10,000 numbers with readout: over 5 minutes

numbers is a list of all numbers (e.g. 2 to 10,000)
i am using colorama and sys modules
primes is also a list of numbers
primetemp is temporary storage for a possible prime (number)

```
while len(numbers)>=1:
    primetemp=numbers[0]
    del numbers[0]
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
    print("Removing multiples of",str(primetemp)+"...", color.BLUE)
    for num in numbers:
        if num%primetemp==0:
            numbers.remove(num)
        else:
            continue
    primes.append(primetemp)
```

Comment: You could make it faster by using the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Your code is not Sieve of Eratosthenes. The whole point of the Sieve is that it saves the previous primes and uses that when testing higher numbers.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia page for it.

Comment: @Barmar *"it saves the previous primes and uses that when testing higher numbers"* - That's not true.

Comment: This question  has been asked before and got several good answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936222/an-efficient-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-python

Comment: This code has multiple places where it performs an O(n) list operation inside the loop, thus making it O(n*n). You have to pay attention to that in python. That could be fixed by using a set instead.

Comment: @KennyOstrom can you elaborate on that?

Comment: see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity "del numbers[0]" and "numbers.remove(num)" are O(n) on a list. However, removing an item from a dict/set is O(1) on average.