# Filter a range without using an intermediate list

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, primes

I have written a function `is-prime` that verifies whether a given number is a prime number or not, and returns `t` or `nil` accordingly.

```
(is-prime 2) ; => T
(is-prime 3) ; => T
(is-prime 4) ; => NIL
```

So far, so good. Now I would like to generate a list of prime numbers between `min` and `max`, so I would like to come up with a function that takes those two values as parameters and returns a list of all prime numbers:

```
(defun get-primes (min max)
  ...)
```

Now this is where I am currently stuck. What I *could* do, of course, is create a list with the range of all numbers from `min` to `max` and run `remove-if-not` on it.

Anyway, this means, that I first have to create a potentially *huge* list with lots of numbers that I throw away anyway. So I would like to do it the other way round, build up a list that contains only the numbers between `min` and `max` that actually are prime according to the `is-prime` predicate.

How can I do this in a **functional** way, i.e. without using `loop`? My current approach (with `loop`) looks like this:

```
(defun get-primes (min max)
  (loop
    for guess from min to max
    when (is-prime guess)
    collect guess))
```

Maybe this is a totally dumb question, but I guess I don't see the forest for the trees.

Any hints?

Comment: I guess you can go recursively through every number anyway and check it. Something like (very rough, haven't done anything in lisp for long)
`(defun primes (start end res)
(cond
(< start end) (primes (+ start 1) end (if (is-prime start) (cons start res) res)
(eq start end) res))`

Comment: Are you expecting `get-primes` to be called with very large `min` values? If not, I would imagine that using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) will be more efficient than whatever your `is-prime` does, and using that would make the question rather moot (since you would be using an array of true/false bits anyway).

Comment: @jkiiski Haha, thanks for pointing this out :-)! Actually, the sieve of Eratosthenes is *exactly* where I'm coming from, and I had memory issues due to a large `max` value, and it was annoying to always have to start at `2` to make sure that even for very large `min` values the correct values are eliminated. So basically, yes, you're right, but I'm coming exactly this way already :-)

Comment: for smaller memory footprint when `min` values are big, use two arrays - a *core* from 2 to `(sqrt max)`, and an *"offset" segment* from `min` to `max`, and [sieve them at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Common Lisp does not favor *pure* *Functional Programming* approaches. The language is based on a more pragmatic view of an underlying machine: no *TCO*, *stacks* are limited, various resources are limited (the number of arguments which are allowed, etc.), *mutation* is possible. That does not sound very motivating for any Haskell enthusiast. But Common Lisp was developed to write Lisp applications, not for advancing FP research and development. Evaluation in Common Lisp (as usual in Lisp) is *strict* and not *lazy*. The default data structures are also not *lazy*. Though there are *lazy* libraries. Common Lisp also does not provide in the standard features like *continuations* or *coroutines* - which might be useful in this case.

The default Common Lisp approach is non-functional and uses some kind of *iteration* construct: `DO`, `LOOP` or the [ITERATE](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) library. Like in your example. Common Lisp users find it perfectly fine. Some, like me, think that *Iterate* is the best looping construct ever invented. ;-) The advantage is that it is relatively easy to create efficient code, even though the macros have a large implementation.

There are various ways to do it differently:

- **lazy streams**. reading SICP helps, see the part on [streams](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%25_sec_3.5). Can be easily done in Common Lisp, too. Note that Common Lisp uses the word `stream` for I/O streams - which is something different.
- use a **generator function** `next-prime`. Generate this function from the initial range and call it until you got all primes you are interested in.

Here is a simple example of a generator function, generating even numbers from some start value:

```
(defun make-next-even-fn (start)
  (let ((current (- start
                    (if (evenp start) 2 1))))
    (lambda ()
      (incf current 2))))


CL-USER 14 > (let ((next-even-fn (make-next-even-fn 13))) 
               (flet ((get-next-even ()
                        (funcall next-even-fn)))
                 (print (get-next-even))
                 (print (get-next-even))
                 (print (get-next-even))
                 (print (get-next-even))
                 (list (get-next-even)
                       (get-next-even)
                       (get-next-even))))

14 
16 
18 
20 
(22 24 26)
```

Defining the `next-prime` generator is left as an exercise. ;-)

- use some kind of more sophisticated lazy data structure. For Common Lisp there is **Series**, which was an early iteration proposal - also published in CLtL2: [Series](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node347.html). The new book [Common Lisp Recipes](http://weitz.de/cl-recipes/) by Edi Weitz (math prof in Hamburg) has a Series example for computing primes. See chapter 7.15. You can download the source code for the book and find the example there.
- the are simpler variants of Series, for example [pipes](https://github.com/pkhuong/Pipes)