# Given that the inputs can be up to 1000000000, how can I write a more time and memory efficient program? (print all primes between m and n)

Tags: c, optimization, time, primes, coding-efficiency

Here is the code below (ans to a CP qs)

The time limit for execution is 6 seconds but my code is slower than.

How can I make it more memory and time efficient ?

- Input: the input begins with the number **t** of test cases in a single line (**t <= 10**).
- In each of the next **t** lines there are two numbers **m** and **n** (**1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000**, **n-m <= 100000**) separated by a space.
- Output : for every test case print all prime numbers **p** such that **m <= p <= n**, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    long int t,m,n,i,j,k;
    //printf("Enter number of testcases:\n");
    scanf("%ld",&t);
    long int test[t][2];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        //printf("Enter m,n:\n");
        scanf("%ld %ld",&test[i][0],&test[i][1]);
    }
    
    for(k=0;k<t;k++){    
        for(i=test[k][0];i<=test[k][1];i++){
            for(j=2;j*j<i*i;j++){
                if(i%j==0)
                    break;
            }
            if(j==i){
                printf("%ld\n",i);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: j times j < i times i - what is that supposed to do?

Comment: The only even prime number is 2.  Apart from that you can ignore even numbers.  Hence, you do not need to test even divisors, `j` > 2.  Test separately for 2 and then start your `j` loop at 3 and step 2

Comment: regarding: ` for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        //printf("Enter m,n:\n");
        scanf("%ld %ld",&test[i][0],&test[i][1]);
    }`   The program only needs to know about 2 values after reading `t`.   Therefore, there is no need to keep all those values,  suggest a simple loop, decrementing `t` until 0 and the body of the loop only has to work with the latest 2 values read from the input.   Also, the functions: `scanf()` and `printf()` are VERY CPU intensive.  Suggest using: `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar_unlocked()`

Comment: accessing the two dimensional array `test[][]` over and over and over` is a real time waster.  Suggest only working with the two inputs of a single test case at a time

Comment: the value: `1000000000` is well within the limits of a `unsigned int` so suggest not using `long int`

Comment: there is nothing in your description of the problem about minimizing the memory consumed.  Therefore, suggest writing a separate program to calculate all the primes from 2 through `10^9` and inserting the results into your 'test' program as `static const` data.  Then the problem solution is a simple: loop through the prime data until one is found that is >= the start value, then output every value encountered until (but not including) the value exceeds the stop value

Comment: OT it is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Nothing in the posted code is using the contents of the header file: `stdlib.h`  Suggest that header file be removed

Comment: regarding: ` for(j=2;j*j<i*i;j++){`  This is a LOT of multiplying that is not needed.  Suggest including `math.h` and calculate `sqrt(i)` into a separate variable, then using that separate variable similar to:  `int sqrt_n = sqrt( n );   for( j=3; j<=sqrt_n; j+=2 )`

Comment: Note: execution time and memory utilization are (almost) always a trade off.

Comment: @user3629249 "there is nothing in your description of the problem about minimizing the memory consumed." it's in the title, and also in the body: "How can I make it more memory and time efficient ?"

Comment: I gave several ideas, in comments, about speeding up the code, because the execution time is limited.  and, as I commented before, execution time and memory usage are a trade off,

Comment: What cpu type have you been given to ask to be under 6s?  time limit has to be engaged to an architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [offset sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19641049/849891), with pseudocode; both links are to SO answers by me).

It is a [segmented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/849891) sieve of Eratosthenes modified to work on only one segment, as per your inputs.

The difference is that a *segmented* sieve proceeds by segments indefinitely and uses as many of the primes as needed by the segment currently being sieved (up to *its* top limit's square root); here the top segment's limit (and hence the core segment's) is known upfront.

The core segment extends up to the *`sqrt`* of the biggest value to be considered; here it is given to you as `10^9`.  `sqrt(10^9) < 32000`, so the core segment spans 0 to 32000, and is sieved by the simple sieve of Eratosthenes.

Since you have several runs, use the same core for each run.

The code in the linked answer is easily amended to this question's requirements: instead of estimating the `top` value, just use the `n` supplied to you in the input. `above` is what's called `m` here.

Comment: in the linked code, regarding: `// 1000 +:  9 13 19 21 31 33 39 49 51 61`   9, 21, 33, 49 are not prime  So if that is an example of the output of the code, then the code is not correct.

Comment: @user3629249 you're misinterpreting the output. the numbers shown are deltas above the limit (here, 1000). that's what the `+` is hinting at.  thus the primes are `1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, ...`. this is done for denser output, esp. with the very big limits.